# How to set an objective to minimize the variance in ratio of allocation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraint-programming, multi-objective-optimization, julia

I am trying to write a model where I have to distribute fractions of rent from properties to loans. The objective is to distribute the rents as equally as possible given the loan balance.

Say there are 5 properties and 8 loans, I have 40 variables X11, X12, X13....X18; X21, X22, X23...X28;......; X51, X52,..X58

Loan Balances are L1, L2, L3, L4 ...L8
Rents from properties are R1,R2, R3, R4 and R5

So Minimize (
Absolute Value (R1 *X11/L1 + R2*X21/L1 + R3*X31/L1 +R4*X41/L1 +R5*X51/L1 - AverageRentLoanRatio) + Abolute Value (R1 *X12/L2 + R2*X22/L2 + R3*X32/L2 +R4*X42/L2 +R5*X52/L2 - AverageRentLoanRatio)+ Abolute Value (R1 *X13/L3 + R2*X23/L3 + R3*X33/L3 +R4*X43/L3 +R5*X53/L3 - AverageRentLoanRatio)+ Abolute Value (R1 *X14/L4 + R2*X24/L4 + R3*X34/L4 +R4*X44/L4 +R5*X54/L4 - AverageRentLoanRatio) + Abolute Value (R1 *X15/L5 + R2*X25/L5 + R3*X35/L5 +R4*X45/L5 +R5*X55/L5 - AverageRentLoanRatio))

With Constraints such as a property cannot be allocated to a specific property and total rent is 100%

I am able to define the constraints but struggling how to write the objective.

Here is the model I have written so far

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
C= CSV.read("Property.csv", DataFrame)
L = CSV.read("LoanFile.csv", DataFrame)



using JuMP, GLPK

# Preparing an optimization model
m = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)


#getting the number of properties and loans
index_i = 1:nrow(C)
index_j = 1:ncol(C)-2

#setting the number of constraints
#index_constraints = 1:nrow(C)* (ncol(C)-2)

# Declaring variables
@variable(m, x[index_i, index_j] >= 0)

# Declaring bound Constraints
@constraint(m, conb[i=index_i, j=index_j],x[i, j] <= C[i,j+2])

#Declaring total 100 % constraints
@constraint(m,cont[i=index_i],sum(x[i, j] * C[i,2] for j in index_j) <= C[i,2])

# Setting the objective
Average_KDF  = sum(C[i,2] for i in 1:nrow(C))/sum(L[i,2] for i in 1:nrow(L))

KDFratio = Array{Float64}(undef,nrow(C),ncol(C)-2)
KDFsumRatio = Array{Float64}(undef,nrow(L))


#@objective(m, Min,sum(abs((x[i, j] * C[i,2]/L[j,2]- Average_KDF) for j in index_j) for i in index_i)
# the above setting of objective is not working and I am struggling to formulate this.
  


# Printing the prepared optimization model

print(m)
```

Here are the files I am using for loans and properties

```
|﻿LoanID  | Balance |
|L 1     |  100.00  |
|L 2     |  100.00  |
|L 3     |  300.00  |
|L 4     |  100.00  |
|L 5     |  50.00   |
|L 6     |  50.00   |
|L 7     |  50.00   |
|L 8     |  50.00   |


|﻿PropertyID  | Rent(R)  |L1|L2|L3|L4|L5|L6|L7|L8|
|P 1         |  5.00    | 1| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0|
|P 2         |  10.00   | 0| 1| 1| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0|
|P 3         |  1.5     | 1| 1| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0|
|P 4         |  10.50   | 1| 1| 1| 1| 0| 0| 0| 0|
|P 5         |  20.00   | 0| 1| 0| 1| 0| 1| 0| 1|
```

Answer (score 2):

In case your solver doesn't provide a constraint to use absolute value like gurobi.absconstraint & since you have minimize as objective any $\vert x-c \vert $ can be written with constraints as
$ x-c \le y$
$ c-x \le y$
$ 0 \le y $
where $x,y$ are your variables with $y \in$ same domain as $x$

Then use $y$ in the objective.

You can consult Cornell optimization [helpsite](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Optimization_with_absolute_values).

Another way I saw somewhere, if linear expressions, with constraints
$ x-c = \mu^+ - \mu^-$
$0 \le \mu^+ , \mu^- $
Then use $ \mu^+ + \mu^-$ in the objective.